# Does Azure web app support out of the box managed clustering and mulit-region failover for node.js?

Tags: azure, node.js

I have read through as much documentation as I can find, and I cant see an answer to this.  MS say hosting of node.js is possible, but they don't seem to say what options, if any, there are for clustering and multi-region failover.

here I am assuming Azure can host node.js apps as a service, not just a VM were we have to install and manage our own node instances and manage clustering ourselves via kubernetes or similar. We don't want to have to touch kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App Service supports NodeJs either directly on App Service, or as a container running on app service, no problem there.

However, App Service is not a multi-region service, if you need failover to a separate region you will need to deploy to an App Service in each region, and add load balancing using something like Azure Front Door or Traffic manager.